# Wordpress menu bar is not showing if i log out of the admin account

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

When i go to my wordpress site, it is not showing the menus. The link of my site is http://www.techjahid.com/wptestsite/
[site not showing menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8akH.png)
But when i login as a admin by going to http://www.techjahid.com/wptestsite/wp-admin/

Then it is showing the menus in the http://www.techjahid.com/wptestsite/wp-admin/
[site showing menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNmZo.png)

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that if the menu bar is in conditional based. Mean to say is that in checking if the user is logged in then only it will display?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the Notice stating you need to define your navigation from Appearance > Menu
Most probably there might be a option for logged in user and for guest.

Comment: There is no option for logged in user and for guest in Appearance > Menu